# ScrollView doesn't scroll swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I have one method that shows a photo and zooms in it if the user wants. I used a scroll view so that the user could scroll if he zooms in a photo. My zoom works but it zoom into the top left corner and my scroll view doesn't scroll anywhere else even though it shows vertical and horizontal bars responsible for scroll moving.

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
var myscrollView: UIScrollView!

var imgView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            myscrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    self.view.addSubview(myscrollView)

    myscrollView.delegate = self
 //  myscrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)

  //  myscrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height), animated: true)
 //   myscrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    print("\(myscrollView.frame.height)  \(myscrollView.frame.width)")
    //myscrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 2000)
    myscrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    myscrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    myscrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0//maximum zoom scale you want
    myscrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    myscrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    myscrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    myscrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    myscrollView.flashScrollIndicators()

  //  scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
  //  self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size * 2//or what ever size you want to set
  //  myscrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((myscrollView.contentSize.width-myscrollView.frame.size.width)*.5f, .0f);//scroll to center
   // myscrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint((myscrollView.contentSize.width-myscrollView.frame.size.width)*.5f, .0f)

    myscrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    //self.view.addSubview(imgView)
    imgView!.layer.cornerRadius = 11.0
    imgView.bounds = myscrollView.bounds
    //imgView!.clipsToBounds = false
    imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
   // imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true
    imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imgView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
   // imgView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myscrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imgView.frame.width , height: 2000)
   // myscrollView.contentSize = imgView.bounds.size

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
  //    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  //        var offsetY: CGFloat!
 //        offsetY = 0;
 //        if (scrollView.zoomScale > 1){
 //            offsetY = CGFloat(scrollView.contentOffset.y);
 //        }
//        //CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: offsetY)
//        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 
 // scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: offsetY), animated: true)
  //
  //       // [aScrollView setContentOffset: 
   // CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x, offsetY)];
   //
 //    }

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imgView
}
//    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
//        myscrollView.delegate = self
//        myscrollView.contentSize = 
//CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)
//    }
//    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
 //        return imgView
 //    }
  }
```

I tried to set contentSize manually to some big or small values and well as using frame.width and height but none of them seem to be working. Can someone please help what is my problem? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try these lines of code and check, What are you missing-

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

let scrollView = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: 1300)
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height-70)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        view.addSubview(scrollView)


}
```

Comment: Also, you may check that, you set the delegate as self

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `scrollViewDidZoom` method as follows;

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.size.width-scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0)
        let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.size.height-scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0, 0)
    }
```